# How to deploy additional test files with .runsettings?

Tags: c#, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I migrated from TPv1 to TPv2 (Test Platform v2). I run my tests by using `vstest.console.exe`. I used `.testsettings` file for deploying additional files that my tests required (usually they are `XML` with some data). The skeleton of my solution is the following:

[image]

My `TestSettings1.testsettings` is the following:

[image]

I use this command for running my tests:

```
@SET LOCAL_SETTINGS=C:\data\Development\Solution14
@SET VSTEST_CONSOLE="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Professional/Common7/IDE/Extensions/TestPlatform/vstest.console.exe"
%VSTEST_CONSOLE% C:\data\Development\Solution14\UnitTestProject1\bin\debug\UnitTestProject1.dll ^
/Settings:%LOCAL_SETTINGS%\TestSettings1.testsettings
```

It's very convenient using `.testsettings` for deploying items.

So, due to some reasons I can't use `.testsettings` any more, but I can use `.runsettings` and `DeploymentItem` attribute.

With `.testsettings` I don't have to add a piece of code to each project in order to deploy my files. I just use `/Settings` flag with `vstest.console.exe` and this deployment applies to project which I want. With `DeploymentItem` I should use some code in each unit test project. These parts of code are the same and I don't like it. I don't want to add the same code to each project.

**The question:** What is the best way to apply the same deployment behavior for each project without writing repetitive code.

Currently I use **build-event**s and `xcopy` in order to copy them to **DeploymentItems** folder (I create it by `mkdir` in build-event) of each **bin/Debug** folder. After that I add `[DeploymentItem("DeploymentItems")]` which deploys all files from this folder. It doesn't looks good because I have 3 identical batch of **build-events** for each `.csproj`. And if I add new `.xml` data I will need to add new **build-even**t instruction to each `.csproj` again. When I used `.testsettings` I didn't have this problem.

Comment: Are the *.xml files copied to the build output folder by setting the **Copy to Output** property to **Copy if Newer**?

Is it an option for you to use **xcopy** in a post-build process to copy the *.xml files to where you need them?

Comment: Yes, currently I use `build-events` and `xcopy` in order to copy them to `DeploymentItems` folder (I create it by `mkdir` in `build-event`) of each `bin/Debug` folder. After that I add `[DeploymentItem("DeploymentItems")]` which deploys all files from this folder. It doesn't looks good because I have 3 identical batch of `build-events` for each `.csproj`. And if I add new `.xml` data I will need to add new `build-event` instruction to each `.csproj` again. When I used `.testsettings` I didn't have this problem.